DISM app associations does completely whatever
I need to update the default files of a few w11 machine, using Dism /Online /Export-DefaultAppAssociations and Import-DefaultAppAssociations I can do this easely. Except not, DISM does shit from a to z, when exporting it returns a super small list with basically only edge on all file types :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
  <Association Identifier=".cab" ProgId="CABFolder" ApplicationName="Windows Explorer" />
  <Association Identifier=".htm" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".html" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".mht" ProgId="MSEdgeMHT" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".mhtml" ProgId="MSEdgeMHT" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".MP2" ProgId="WMP11.AssocFile.MP3" ApplicationName="Windows Media Player Legacy" />
  <Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgId="MSEdgePDF" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".svg" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".tif" ProgId="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff" ApplicationName="Windows Photo Viewer" />
  <Association Identifier=".tiff" ProgId="PhotoViewer.FileAssoc.Tiff" ApplicationName="Windows Photo Viewer" />
  <Association Identifier=".url" ProgId="InternetShortcut" ApplicationName="Internet Browser" />
  <Association Identifier=".xht" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".xhtml" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier=".zip" ProgId="CompressedFolder" ApplicationName="Windows Explorer" />
  <Association Identifier="ftp" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier="http" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier="https" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier="microsoft-edge" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier="microsoft-edge-holographic" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier="ms-xbl-3d8b930f" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
  <Association Identifier="read" ProgId="MSEdgeHTM" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" />
</DefaultAssociations>

For some mysterious reason, dism /online /Get-DefaultAppAssociations retruns a completely different list that is much longer and actually looks like something :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DefaultAssociations>
  <Association Identifier=".3g2" ProgId="AppXqj98qxeaynz6dv4459ayz6bnqxbyaqcs" ApplicationName="Media Player" OverwriteOnVersionMax="44" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX6eg8h5sxqq90pv53845wmnbewywdqq5h;AppXhjhjmgrfm2d7rd026az898dy2p1pcsyt;WMP11.AssocFile.3G2" />
...
  <Association Identifier=".orf" ProgId="AppX9rkaq77s0jzh1tyccadx9ghba15r6t3h" ApplicationName="Photos" OverwriteOnVersionMax="48" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX9vdwcvrwnbettpahnt26jswq0n8hgyah;AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc;Paint.Paint;Microsoft.PhotoManager.imagetype" />
  <Association Identifier=".oxps" ProgId="Windows.XPSReachViewer" ApplicationName="XPS Viewer" OverwriteOnVersionMax="1" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX86746z2101ayy2ygv3g96e4eqdf8r99j" />
  <Association Identifier=".pdf" ProgId="MSEdgePDF" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" OverwriteOnVersionMax="1" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppXk660crfh0gw7gd9swc1nws708mn7qjr1;AppX86746z2101ayy2ygv3g96e4eqdf8r99j" />
  <Association Identifier=".pef" ProgId="AppX9rkaq77s0jzh1tyccadx9ghba15r6t3h" ApplicationName="Photos" OverwriteOnVersionMax="48" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX9vdwcvrwnbettpahnt26jswq0n8hgyah;AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc;Paint.Paint;Microsoft.PhotoManager.imagetype" />
...

Even then, the output has nothing to see whith what is actually used by windows on the current version, see .pdf for exemple : edge in export, chrome in reality.
How can I make DISM actually do it's job or use an other tool that would work in CLI for this job ?

Are they existing users your trying to update? It may not be possible to use dism https://stackoverflow.com/a/38234773/212869

there are users locally on each machine, and independently the update must be system wide. I will look at GPO
